# Searching for a Variable Defined in Excel Spreadsheet Formulas

Tags: excel

In the excel sheet I have one cell which is represented by "My_Variable" name. Is there anyway to search for the usage of "My_Variable" in all the formulas used by that excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the Find Dialogue with ctrl+f
2. For the Find what, type in: my_variable
3. Click Options to expand the options section
4. For Within, select Workbook
5. For Look In, select Formulas
6. Click Find All